# Simultaneous lock and use of SQL Server 2008 table in a c# project?

Tags: c#, sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking, deadlock

I have a SQL Server table and this table will be updated by a batch job every 5 minutes using backgroundworker multithread calls. Also i am using thread lock when i am inserting the table via batch job. The same data can be accessed by the user of the application simultaneously. I have my business logic in C#. What is the best and optimized solution for this? Can i use thread lock on this situation or not?

Comment: Just let SQL Server handle this - that's what it's made for! Just try to avoid updating more than 5'000 rows in a single batch run - otherwise, your entire table might get an **exclusive lock** placed on it and no reading of data would be possible anymore until that (X) lock is freed again

Comment: I am doing some explicit lock via thread for batch job sql update. Is this required or sql will handle this? private Object thisLock = new Object(); lock (thisLock) { <<sql update>> }

Comment: That's just .NET locking - has **nothing** to do with and no impact on the database **AT ALL**!

Answer (score 1):

What's the problem you have (or that you anticipate)?

SQL Server is **made and optimized** for handling lots of concurrent connections and users updating, inserting, reading data. Just let it handle the work!

When your background worker thread updates the table, it will take **exclusive (X) locks** on those rows that it updates - but **only** on those rows (as long as you don't update more than 5000 rows at once).

During that time, any other row in the table can be read - no problem at all, no deadlock in sight....

The problem *could* occur if you update more than 5000 rows in a single transaction - then SQL Server will do a **Lock escalation** to avoid having to keep track of too many locks, and it will lock the entire table with an (X) lock. Until the end of that update transaction - no reads are possible anymore - but those are normal transactional locks - **NOT** deadlocks.

So where is your problem / your issue?

Comment: I am doing some explicit lock via thread for batch job sql update. Is this required or sql will handle this?

      private Object thisLock = new Object();
      lock (thisLock)
      {

      <<sql update>>
      
      }

Comment: @SelvakumarM.M: SQL Server handles all of this automatically - I would try to **avoid** doing any explicit locking unless you **absolutely** must....